# invertible matrices and demensions

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to provide a proposal for solving the following tasks. 
I am new in this topic and have not that much experience and knowledge yet.

[the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3PAP.png)

$$A= \left[\begin{matrix} 0 &-1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$

a) Calculate $A²$, $A³$, $A⁴$. Is $A$ invertible?

b) Determine a Basis and the Dimension of $T = span\{A, A², A³,..., A¹⁰\}$

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: "a proposal for solving the following tasks": compute.

Comment: What have you learnt about matrices and where have you faced the problem? It would be much easier to answer your question if you would provide a little background.....You can edit the question using the 'edit' option below the tags of the question to add in that info.... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the action of the matrix $A$ on a vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$, i.e. find $A\mathbf{x}$. So
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{A} \begin{bmatrix}-y\\x\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{A} \begin{bmatrix}-x\\-y\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{A} \begin{bmatrix}y\\-x\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{A} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}.$$
This tells you that 
$$A^4\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x} \implies A^4=I.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, yes I think so, could you additionally show me the LaTeX code you used to depict the content of the image, and possibly also that of your answer?

Comment: @Lampert12 click "edit" to see the LaTeX code.